# jQueryのcrossDomainオプションが効かない

Tags: javascript, jquery

http://example.com から、以下のコードを実行すると、

```
var url = 'http://www.yahoo.co.jp';

$.ajax(url, {
  crossDomain: true,
  success: function(res) {
    console.log(res);
  }
});
```

以下のようなエラー表示されます。

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.yahoo.co.jp. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://**.**.**.**' is therefore not allowed access.
```

crossDomainオプションを有効にしているのになぜでしょうか？

Answer (score 5, accepted):

クロスドメインでアクセスする場合はアクセス先のサーバーがレスポンスのヘッダに　`Access-Control-Allow-Origin` を追加していない限りアクセスすることはできません。

アクセス先の設定をいじれない場合は [`jquery.xdomainajax.js`](https://github.com/padolsey/jquery.fn/blob/master/cross-domain-ajax/jquery.xdomainajax.js) というプラグインを使用するとアクセスできるようです。

下のコードで動作確認は出来ましたが、 `jquery.xdomainajax.js` は Yahoo API を経由してレスポンスを取得するという実装のため Yahoo! 側が API の提供を停止する等してしまうと使用不能になるかもしれません。

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http:////ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./jquery.xdomainajax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        var url = 'http://www.yahoo.co.jp';
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $.ajax({
                url:url,
                type: 'GET',
                cache: false,
                success: function(res) {
                    console.log(res);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

`jQuery.ajax()`の`crossDomain`オプションは[公式リファレンス](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)によると

> **crossDomain** (default: `false for same-domain requests, true for cross-domain requests`)
>   Type: Boolean
>   If you wish to force a crossDomain request (such as JSONP) on the same domain, set the value of crossDomain to `true`. This allows, for example, server-side redirection to another domain. **(version added: 1.5)**

ということであり、「クロスドメイン通信したいです」と設定するものではなく、「同ドメイン上でクロスドメインっぽく通信したいです」という設定をするもののようです。

実際にクロスドメイン通信ができない理由はsige yangさんがおっしゃるように、リクエスト先のサーバーが`Access-Control-Allow-Origin`ヘッダーにリクエスト元を含めてくれていないからです。

`jQuery.ajax()`の`crossDomain`オプションがどのように作用するのかリクエストヘッダーを見た結果を以下に添付します。

1. クロスドメインで`crossDomain`を`true`にした場合

   ```
   GET /?_=1422345793807 HTTP/1.1
   Host: www.yahoo.co.jp
   Connection: keep-alive
   Accept: */*
   Origin: http://ja.stackoverflow.com
   User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.91 Safari/537.36
   DNT: 1
   Referer: http://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/5406/jquery%e3%81%aecrossdomain%e3%82%aa%e3%83%97%e3%82%b7%e3%83%a7%e3%83%b3%e3%81%8c%e5%8a%b9%e3%81%8b%e3%81%aa%e3%81%84
   Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
   Accept-Language: ja,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
   ```
2. クロスドメインで`crossDomain`を`false`にした場合

   ```
   OPTIONS /?_=1422345943662 HTTP/1.1
   Host: www.yahoo.co.jp
   Connection: keep-alive
   Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
   Origin: http://ja.stackoverflow.com
   User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.91 Safari/537.36
   Access-Control-Request-Headers: accept, x-requested-with
   Accept: */*
   DNT: 1
   Referer: http://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/5406/jquery%e3%81%aecrossdomain%e3%82%aa%e3%83%97%e3%82%b7%e3%83%a7%e3%83%b3%e3%81%8c%e5%8a%b9%e3%81%8b%e3%81%aa%e3%81%84
   Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
   Accept-Language: ja,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
   ```
3. 同ドメインで`crossDomain`を`true`にした場合

   ```
   GET /questions/5406/jquery%E3%81%AEcrossdomain%E3%82%AA%E3%83%97%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A7%E3%83%B3%E3%81%8C%E5%8A%B9%E3%81%8B%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84?_=1422346041101 HTTP/1.1
   Host: ja.stackoverflow.com
   Connection: keep-alive
   Accept: */*
   User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.91 Safari/537.36
   DNT: 1
   Referer: http://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/5406/jquery%e3%81%aecrossdomain%e3%82%aa%e3%83%97%e3%82%b7%e3%83%a7%e3%83%b3%e3%81%8c%e5%8a%b9%e3%81%8b%e3%81%aa%e3%81%84
   Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
   Accept-Language: ja,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
   Cookie: __qca=P0-1411648952-1418703068360; usr=t=nDf3Q2CrkkWh&s=7muexQo30CrB; _ga=GA1.2.1581710640.1418703068; __cfduid=d0399dc82953e8eaf559a1655c6da639e1422239231; sgt=id=dc0a90b3-67f2-4f8b-bf96-1907b718803b; _ga=GA1.3.1581710640.1418703068; acct=t=Vwpz8j9lJUBoz4SgBQrYvpa2GV85zbWp&s=gacZfjyUemiWR1NH0/x1mObJofJ0rwh+; jauser=t=2YRIB2kcUkno&s=B3s4tM0fEOvh
   ```
4. 同ドメインで`crossDomain`を`false`にした場合

   ```
   GET /questions/5406/jquery%E3%81%AEcrossdomain%E3%82%AA%E3%83%97%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A7%E3%83%B3%E3%81%8C%E5%8A%B9%E3%81%8B%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84?_=1422346068309 HTTP/1.1
   Host: ja.stackoverflow.com
   Connection: keep-alive
   Accept: */*
   X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
   User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.91 Safari/537.36
   DNT: 1
   Referer: http://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/5406/jquery%e3%81%aecrossdomain%e3%82%aa%e3%83%97%e3%82%b7%e3%83%a7%e3%83%b3%e3%81%8c%e5%8a%b9%e3%81%8b%e3%81%aa%e3%81%84
   Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
   Accept-Language: ja,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
   Cookie: __qca=P0-1411648952-1418703068360; usr=t=nDf3Q2CrkkWh&s=7muexQo30CrB; _ga=GA1.2.1581710640.1418703068; __cfduid=d0399dc82953e8eaf559a1655c6da639e1422239231; sgt=id=dc0a90b3-67f2-4f8b-bf96-1907b718803b; _ga=GA1.3.1581710640.1418703068; acct=t=Vwpz8j9lJUBoz4SgBQrYvpa2GV85zbWp&s=gacZfjyUemiWR1NH0/x1mObJofJ0rwh+; jauser=t=2YRIB2kcUkno&s=B3s4tM0fEOvh
   ```

同ドメインで`crossDomain`を`true`にすると`X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest`を送らなくなるようですね。クロスドメインで`crossDomain`による差異はわりとあるのでここでは割愛しますが、少なくともともかくリクエストの仕方に違いが出るようですね。

Answer (score 1):

以下で試して貰えますか。

```
var url = 'http://www.yahoo.co.jp';

$.ajax({
  url,
  crossDomain: true,
  success: function(res) {
    console.log(res);
  }
});
```

Comment: もちろんCORSである前提ですので sige yang さんの指摘がパスしているのが条件です。